# Open two reports simultaneously on one OnAction

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-business-central

I am trying to open two of the same report (different filters) when clicking on the print PDF function. I want to be able to open both reports clicking this rather than repeating myself.

Currently I am able to open one of the reports, NAV will flash at me in the task bar and another window will prompt, I will click the print PDF option again and the second report will open.

I understand this is because of the second CLEAR line but when I remove that line it throws up an error saying that line needs to be inserted.

```
CLEAR(Report01);

SalesHeader.RESET;

SalesHeader.SETRANGE    ("Document Type","Document Type");

SalesHeader.SETRANGE    ("No.","No.");

Report01.SetExampleOne;

Report01.SETTABLEVIEW   (SalesHeader);

Report01.RUNMODAL;

CLEAR   (Report1); 


SalesHeader.RESET; 


SalesHeader.SETRANGE    ("Document Type","Document Type");


SalesHeader.SETRANGE    ("No.","No.");


Report1.SetExample2;


Report1.SETTABLEVIEW    (SalesHeader);


Report1.RUNMODAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Report.RUN` instead of `Runmodal`. Modal window mean exactly one window will be opened and rest will be postponed.

Comment: Still the same thing happening. I am trying to do this all in one PDF click if thats possible.

Comment: Try to set `UseRequestPage` property of the report to `false`.

Comment: UseRequestPage is automatically printing both reports and not giving me the chance to select print - pdf.

Comment: Then don’t run it. Use SaveAsPdf instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/saveaspdf-function--report-